# How to duplicate a hypothesis in Coq?

Tags: coq

During a proof, I encountered an hypothesis `H`. I have lemmas: `H -> A` and `H -> B`.

How can I duplicate `H` in order to deduce two hypotheses `A` and `B` ?

**edited**:
More precisely, I have:

```coq
lemma l1: X -> A.
lemma l2: X -> B.

1 subgoals, subgoal 1 (ID: 42)
H: X
=========
Y
```

But, I want to get:

```coq
1 subgoals, subgoal 1 (ID: 42)
H1: A
H2: B
=========
Y
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you absolutely need to use an assumption multiple times as you suggested, you can use forward-reasoning tactics such as `assert` to do so without clearing it from the context, e.g.

```
assert (HA := l1 H).
assert (HB := l2 H).
```

You can also do something like `assert (H' := H).` to explicitly copy `H` into `H'`, although you can usually resort to a more direct way for getting what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that you need to duplicate the hypothesis? If you are using it in a proof, it won't become unavailable. See this example:

```
Parameter A B H : Type.
Parameter lemma1 : H -> A.
Parameter lemma2 : H -> B.

Goal H -> A * B.
intro; split; [apply lemma1 | apply lemma2]; assumption.
Qed.
```

Comment: I need both hypotheses A and B to prove a single goal. I can not split it. And when I do `apply lemma1 in H` H indeed gets unavailable and is replaced by A.

Comment: I extended my question with a sketch of the required transformation. As I said `apply l1 in H` replaces X to A inplace, so after it I can not `apply l2 in H`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to duplicate hypothesis `H`, you can `pose proof H as G`. `G` is the name you choose for the generated hypothesis. `as G` can be omitted, in this way you let coq choose the name.